# How to sign: "DATED: _____, State of California, ____ 2015" If I don't live in California?

Tags: united-states

I'm about to accept an internship. The agreement looks like something like this:

```
DATED: _____, State of California, ____ 2015
```

I currently don't live in the State of California. What should I put in the city? Should I put the company's HQ? Or should I write my state underneath the "State of California".

Comment: Is there any money (or other consideration) involved? If not, then I suspect it does not matter at all.

Comment: You should probably ask the people you are signing it for.

Answer (score 3):

This is just referring to the state who's laws govern the agreement (and the signature), though they really need to understand that "State of XXX" is NOT a **date**.

I'd just sign it knowing that California laws govern the agreement.  California has some of the higher protections in the US for employees, so it's actually a good thing for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that they intend to fill in those blanks when they accept the form rather than expecting you to do so ... but call them and ask; that's *much* more reliable than asking us..

Comment: +1 When confused: just ask. OP probably isn't the first to be confused about this, and probably not the last either.